# Unable to install Counter Strike: Global Offensive on 15.10

Tags: games, steam

I get the following message when trying to install CS:GO via Steam:

```
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive in not available on your current platform.
```

I am running up to date 15.10. My hardware is:

```
i7-3520M with Intel® HD Graphics 4000
```

Older Counter-Strike versions install fine.

Comment: Did you install Steam from the Software Center, or from Steam's website? I downloaded Steam from the official website, and I can install (and play) CS:GO just fine.

Comment: I have originally installed it from the Software Center and today updated it with a dpkg from [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Ubuntu). Will try to reinstall it completely.

Comment: I can install the game after complete reinstall of steam. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete re-installation of Steam fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some recommendations that is much better to install steam from software center, it worked for me and I did this yesterday(12.02.2016).